# haskell Binary Tree exercises

Tags: haskell

In Graham Hutton's book Programming in Haskell, there was an error in solving Chapter 10 Exercise 3.

When the number of leaves on the left and right side trees is not more than one, these trees are said to be balanced.
Of course, it seems to be balanced by itself. Define a function to determine if the tree is balanced.
First, define a function that counts how many leaves are in the tree.

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Tree Tree

leaves :: Tree -> Int
leaves (Leaf _) = 1 leaves 
leaves (Node l r) = leaves l + leaves r

balanced :: Tree -> Bool
(-) :: Int -> Int -> Integer
balanced (Leaf _) = True
balanced (Node l r) = abs (leaves l - leaves r) <= 1
&& balanced l && balanced r
```

I do not know anything about Haskell, but my professor gave me the assignment. Help

Comment: `leaves (Leaf _) ` should be just `1`.   My suggestion implement this function with any other language you're comfortable with.  Once you understand how to implement, it will be easier to comprehend this solution.

Comment: Sorry. The leaves next to the number 1 are typographical errors

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. You've provided the solution to your assignment in the question. (Though, you don't need the `&& balanced l && balanced r` part, I don't think - seems redundant).

Comment: It does not run in ghci.

Comment: @KimHanSol if you notice errors in your question (e.g. the typographical one), make sure to [edit] it.

Comment: A handy hint: if you get an error when trying to run in GHCi, paste that into your question, too. It's possibly one of the most important parts - we need to see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks mostly fine, but you have some minor errors.

```
leaves :: Tree -> Int
leaves (Leaf _) = 1         -- not 1 leaves
leaves (Node l r) = leaves l + leaves r

balanced :: Tree -> Bool
-- don't declare (-) here, it's already declared by the libraries!
balanced (Leaf _) = True
balanced (Node l r) = abs (leaves l - leaves r) <= 1
   && balanced l && balanced r   -- indent this more
```